# PHP - Why do you need to use $this-> to call a method within its class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

What is the utility of requiring the `$this->` before calling a method from within its own (or a child's) class?  What is this meant to prevent? Wouldn't it be logical to think that the engine should look within the class by default?

Comment: @meagar: Unlike Ruby, which is perfect, right?

Comment: @Michael Like looking upon the face of God if God were made out of adorable fluffy kittens and everything were wonderful forever. But don't take my word for it, I only worked with PHP for a decade and Ruby for less than two years. I think I would quit software development forever before going back.

Comment: @meagar: So long as God has unlimited RAM.

Comment: @meagar I don't think that such a small issue can ruin a whole language or mean bad design. C++ is full of weird and bizarre syntax issues. Probably you are just a web dev ;)

Comment: Fight! Fight! Fight! ... yeah, this better get deleted now.

Comment: @Michael ... I'm pretty sure he does, dude. It's **God**.

Comment: @Jack This is just one of [many reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309300/what-makes-php-a-good-language) why PHP is a poorly designed language.

Comment: @meagar: You're right, I withdraw.

Comment: Surely the requirement of `this->` is not considerable a bad design choice. Since we're not talking about the design of PHP but we're talking about a specific thing having to listen to your unrelated opinions is just useless and redundant. I guess you understand what I mean..

Comment: Since we're complaining about languages, boy do I dislike Python's syntax. And I am diametrically opposed to French.

Comment: Then IMHO any language that doesn't provide strong static type safety is a badly designed language. So yes, either PHP and Ruby are badly designed languages. ;) (no, I'm not kidding.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
function bar()
{
    echo "Outside\n";
}

class foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        bar();
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        echo "Inside\n";
    }
}

new foo;
```

So, without `$this->` prefixing the constructor's call to `bar()`, PHP calls the outside function and not the method. Using `$this->` eliminates the ambiguity and precisely defines which function you want to call.

If what you have suggested were true (auto searching the class), then as far as I know (waiting for crazy unreadable hack in comments), it would be impossible in PHP for a class method to call a function in the global scope that has the same name as another class method.

Comment: Ahaha, I knew it. Can't believe I forgot `call_user_func`, as I've had several use cases for `call_user_func_array`. Still harder to read than `bar();`!

Comment: Yeah, well, I couldn't resist :) Too bad there's no `::bar()`.

Comment: You'd think with all the syntax adopted from C++ that they'd incorporate `::bar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it might be logical. It's also not how PHP is built. Same as in JavaScript, too:

```
var x = {a: 0, f: function() { alert(a); }};
x.f(); // TypeError, a isn't defined
```

... and many other languages. I suppose they didn't want to break the global scope. Is it really that much of an issue compared to all of PHP's other problems? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not practical with php but often it's a matter of readability.

It can help also avoiding name clashes when you have a global method that has the same name of the one of the class.